# How to input from keyboard when debugging using gdb remote mode?

Tags: gdb, gdbserver

I am using gdb to debug the following program in ubuntu 16.04.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    cout<<n<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When I debug it locally, I am able to input data using keyboard. However, when I debug using gdb server, I get stuck when I try to input data using stdin. Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: You could run your program, find the process ID (e.g., xxxx) for the program. Open gdb with "$ gdb -pid xxxx"or if gdb is open "(gdb) attach xxxx". You may need to sudo gdb first. This works better if you are using screen or tmux, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, `gdbserver` won't help you in this case (for now). It simply starts the program using `gdbserver`'s tty, which is on the remote machine. This is unfortunate because GDB remote protocol [has extensions to manage this](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/File_002dI_002fO-Overview.html), but `gdbserver` doesn't implement it (so far).

So you have to manage your program's tty yourself. The most complete solution is using `socat` to create a "remote TTY" for you and your program.

On the remote machine:

```
$ socat TCP-LISTEN:12345 EXEC:'<your program>',ptmx
```

The option `ptmx` allows to use a PTY as inter-process communication mechanism instead of a `socketpair`. It will give you finer grained control on buffering using tty settings, directly built in `socat`'s CLI (cf. `man socat`). In this default case, it simply buffers until a newline character is written by `<your program>`.

On the other side, run:

```
$ socat - TCP:localhost:12345
```

And now you have your remote TTY, besides GDB's.
It supposes that you can run `socat` on your target and that you can connect to it through a TCP network.

If you can't, you could also use a free serial line, `stty` your settings and run your program against it using shell redirections:

```
$ stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 raw 9600
$ exec command <> /dev/ttyUSB0 >&0 2>&1
```

As explained in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/170063/start-a-process-on-a-different-tty).

Anyway, you definitely should wrap your solution and `gdbserver` has a `--wrapper` option allowing you to script the way the program is run when using `--multi`.

Note that using multi-inferior solutions to remotely run `socat` and automatically attach to the forked program, the one you want to debug, are too buggy for now to be explained and used.